# Vectorized pd.str.replace

Tags: python, pandas, string

I've got two dataframes

One with the rule -different rules, depending on some conditions

```
        Value 1     Value2
Cond1   x> 2.5     x>5
Cond2   2.5>x>1    5>x>0
```

And one with different values of x

```
   Value1   Value2
      0       6
      2       3
```

And I want to use the dataframe of condition in order to evaluate the values of x.
I can use a loop, like

```
for value in Data_value : 
    Data_evaluate.str.replace("x",str(Data_value))
```

but it can take lot of time since there are lot of values of x.

I tried also to use directly the method

```
Data_evaluate.str.replace("x",Data_value.apply(str))
```

but it doesn't work, since it supports only string, and not Dataseries of string.

Is there a way to vectorize this problem ?

Thanks